# File or database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have three tables with 5 columns each. They can grow upto 15 rows each.
Does it make sense to have a SQLite database for this or should a file suffice? I am talking about pure performance basis.

Comment: I see the tag android, if you are doing it in android, why don't you use Sqlite ?

Comment: I think the poster meant to say SQLite.

Comment: I did mean, SQLite. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance point of view this will matter very little, but from a maintenance point of view you should go with the sql approach, stay clear of any arcane home-brew approaches if there is a general well-known way of doing something :)
Also it should be a lot faster to write the code for the database rather that for the flat file. And, never optimize until you can measure and see that you have a performance issue.

Answer (score 3):

my suggestion is to go for `Sqlite`, Sqlite having cursor which can navigate data, modify data very easily.

The same thing with `File` is quite complex, for that you have to do string function like `indexOf()`, `subString()`, `replace()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need any sort of concurrency support? If so, SQLite would make sense, rather than building that yourself.

I would side with using a database, since it would likely be easier to maintain the integrity of your data, with respect to relationships and the format of the data you're storing. Making an error when updating a table is easy to notice (exceptions are nice to prevent corrupt data), but writing out malformed data to your own format might not be easy to spot until it's too late.

Performance should probably come second to maintaining valid data.

Comment: A very valid point. Much benefits comes from reusing well known and well tested packages/patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I would also clearly vote for the DB solution. Additionally to the mentioned advantages, it's a good thing to learn anyway - and - honestly - at the end considering all issues it's not harder or more work than the file system solution.

By the way, back then I learned the DB with this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

It was alos very usefull for couple of other reasons...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a MySQL database and don't need any tricky joins, go with the filesystem.

I do web, not android, but I've had great success consuming JSON manifests out of the filesystem using JavaScript.  It's so nice to cut the database overhead, and the filesystem is practically instant.